# Vertical / Horizontal Scroll Bar won't appear when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css

I just noticed upon resizing my browser, there isn't any scroll bar that appears?! isn't this supposed to be automatic upon resizing a browser window?

I've tried this code I found on another post

```
@media (min-width:848px) {
  html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```

but nothing really happened..so I removed it.

here's how it looks like resized
[image]

and on fullscreen

[image]

help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your full code including the HTML?

Comment: You're probably using `%` units. try setting a minimum value using `min-width` , `min-height` so that after that point, scroll will appear

Comment: @TJ 
 
Hi, the min-width & min-height worked for the background but it breaks the positioning T_T and does not affect the pop up modal box that is shown, even if I scroll up and down / left right it's still stuck in the same view.

http://imgur.com/WCxZ8Qr  (when pop up modal box is open)

http://imgur.com/6IxrxwV (when pop up modal box is closed)

Comment: @Allocen can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something with some sample code demonstrating your issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure without html structure, but try to swap overflows, because overflow-y scroll is the one you want to appear:

```
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: scroll;
```

or you could try:

```
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
```

so the scrollbar will hide if it is not necessary.